# Showing percentage (%) sign in using xtabs

Tags: r, number-formatting, crosstab

Having column data with binary targets:

```
> XYp <- data.frame(X=floor(3*runif(100)),Y=floor(3*runif(1000)),p=round(runif(1000)))
> head(XYp)
  X Y p
1 0 2 0
2 0 1 1
3 0 1 1
4 1 0 1
5 1 1 0
6 2 1 1
```

I have managed to cross tabulate average target `xtabs`:

```
> xtabs(p ~ X + Y, aggregate(p ~ X + Y, XYp, mean))
   Y
X           0         1         2
  0 0.4552846 0.4652778 0.4878049
  1 0.5436893 0.4907407 0.6067416
  2 0.6018519 0.5346535 0.6435644
```

Now I would like to show the result in percentages, with the percentage sign (%), but so far I could only get results without the percentage sign:

```
> xt <- xtabs(p ~ X + Y, aggregate(p ~ X + Y, XYp, x <- function(x) round(mean(x),4)))
> xt
   Y
X        0      1      2
  0 0.4553 0.4653 0.4878
  1 0.5437 0.4907 0.6067
  2 0.6019 0.5347 0.6436
```

I tried to manipulate `xtabs` output, but so far I could apply numeric transformations:

```
> xt*100
   Y
X       0     1     2
  0 45.53 46.53 48.78
  1 54.37 49.07 60.67
  2 60.19 53.47 64.36
```

and did not get the percentage sign (%) after each element in the crosstabulation. Is it possible to get the percentage sign there, or should one use some other data structure?

Comment: So the solution is to convert xtabs as a matrix?

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate: `xt2 <- as.matrix(xt); xt2[] <- sprintf("%.2f%%",100*xt); xt2`